# Awk code working in the command line but not in my script

Tags: awk

I'm asking because a tried other solutions from other questions here, but non of them seems to work for me. I guess is a simple thing but I can't find the information.

This is working well in the command:

```
awk -F, '$4 == "finnish" && $5 ~ /swedish/' file.csv
```

and I need to run it but in a script using this code in the command line:

```
gawk -f script.awk file.csv
```

My script is this one now:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

-F, $4 == "finnish" && $5 ~ /swedish/
```

I tried all type of combinations but is not even showing an error, it shows no output. I tried deleting -f and -F, also using other sintax, but still it shows no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{FS=","}
$4 == "finnish" && $5 ~ /swedish/
```